# Coerce raster time series (rts) object back to raster* object

Tags: r, raster

Should seem straight forward but have failed to find a way. How does one coerce a rts raster time series back to a raster (stack)?

The following example from the rts package.

```
library(raster)
library(rts)
path <- system.file("external", package="rts")
lst <- list.files(path=path,pattern='.asc$',full.names=TRUE)
r <- stack(lst)
d <- c("2000-02-01","2000-03-01","2000-04-01","2000-05-01") # corresponding dates to 4 rasters
d <- as.Date(d)

# creating a RasterStackTS object:
rt <- rts(r,d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In rts, the raster object is kept in slot @raster, so, you can simply use `rt@raster` to get the raster object.

Comment: This is the very only place in the web were you can find this information. I'd give you not 1 but 10000 upvotes